Cannot eject USB memory card either in Finder or through umount
Often when external SD or Micro SD cards are mounted on the Desktop, I cannot eject/unmount them. The only operation I have done on the card(s) is to open them, copy and/or delete files. Other than the Finder I don't access the card in any other application.
In the Finder the error message box says:
The disk "MEMORY CARD" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it. Buttons are Cancel or Force Eject, which I always cancel out of.
In the terminal (bash) I navigate to /VOLUMES and try to use umount:
$ sudo umount ./MEMORY\ CARD
umount(/Volumes/MEMORY CARD): Resource busy -- try 'diskutil unmount'
$ diskutil unmount MEMORY\ CARD
Volume MEMORY CARD on disk3s1 failed to unmount: dissented by PID 422 (/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/QuickLookUIService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/QuickLookUIService)
Dissenter parent PPID 1 (/sbin/launchd)

The only way I can safely unmount the card is to log out or force-quit the finder. This seems rather extreme.

How is the card formatted?

SD cards from cameras are formatted either FAT32 or ExFAT, always done by the camera. USB drives are either ExFAT or MacOS Extended (journaled). The ejecting problem can happen to all formats.

Please try adding the cards to the Search Privacy list in the Spotlight settings. Also exclude them from Time Machine backups, if not already excluded. They still need to be backed up, of course.

Siri and time machine are completely disabled on my system, and spotlight does not have permission to search anywhere. I use multiple SD cards and USB drives. I can never predict whether or when any given card/drive will get stuck, it happens randomly.

Welcome to Ask Different. From diskutil unmount's output, there seems to be a Quick Look process using the card, could it be that you've selected a file on the card and pressed space? What is the output of sudo lsof /Volumes/MEMORY\ CARD? (Modify the path to the memory card if necessary.)

What macOS version?

three trial ejects: 1. open card and folder, close folder trash-eject. success.
2. open card and folder, click-space quicklook, close image and folder, trash-eject fail; lsof output + diskutil unmount success:
:Volumes $ sudo lsof ./CANON_DC/

COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mds     121 root   25r   DIR   1,12   131072    4 ./CANON_DC
:mds     121 root   28r   DIR   1,12   131072    4 ./CANON_DC
:Volumes $ diskutil unmount ./CANON_DC/
Volume CANON_DC on disk2s1 unmounted


if I don't close the quicklook  the image window floats above all others.


System Version: macOS 12.7.6 (21H1320)
Kernel Version: Darwin 21.6.0

I sometimes had problems ejecting external drives in some older versions of macOS. I think it was a bug, which seems to have been fixed in Sequoia, or maybe earlier. You haven't identified your Mac model, but if it can be upgraded to a newer macOS version, I suggest you try that.

MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) Can't upgrade to Sequoia. This problem started within the last year or so. I certainly never had it before 2022.

Please boot in Safe Mode and test. If the problem is not reproducible in Safe Mode, it's probablly caused by a software conflict.

Whatever mode I boot in has no effect on whether the failure to eject will or won't happen. I use multiple SD cards and USB sticks on multiple occasions. The failure to eject happens randomly and may or may not happen to the same card/stick.

As I wrote above, I think it's a bug. I don't know what, if anything, can be done about it, as you can't upgrade the OS. When I had the issue I would sometimes lose patience and hit the "Force Eject" button, but that's risky with a memory card. You need good backups.
